# proof of dot product in terms of norms

Tags: linear-algebra

The textbook I'm using doesn't provide a complete proof of the following theorem and I am having difficulty proving it myself.

$$
\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v} = 
\frac{1}{4}\|\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v}\|^2 -
\frac{1}{4}\|\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}\|^2
$$

The textbook also states that this is a dot product in terms of norms.

Answer (score 3):

This  is known as the polarization identity (more or less). Start from this:
$$
\|a\|^2 = a \cdot a
$$
for any $a$. Apply this to $a = u + v$ to get
\begin{align}
\| u + v \| ^2 &= (u+v) \cdot (u + v)\\
 &= u \cdot u + 2 u \cdot v + v \cdot v
\end{align}
and similarly
\begin{align}
\| u - v \| ^2 &= (u-v) \cdot (u - v)\\
 &= u \cdot u - 2 u \cdot v + v \cdot v
\end{align}
Subtract to get
\begin{align}
\| u + v \| ^2 - \|u - v \|^2 
 &= u \cdot u + 2 u \cdot v + v \cdot v
-( u \cdot u - 2 u \cdot v + v \cdot v) \\
&= 4 u \cdot v
\end{align}
and then divide by $4$.

Note that this only works if you can divide by $4$, so when you're working in a vector space whose base field has characteristic $2$, for instance, this theorem no longer applies. (And if that makes no sense at all to you, feel free to ignore it -- it just means you haven't yet encountered some more complicated generalizations in linear algebra.)

Comment: Thanks, mate. Really appreciate it.